# what permissions to set for SuiteCRM to load files correctly?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

i have SuiteCRM version 7.8.3 on Win server 2012 r2 iis,i have problems uploading files,
firstly, i wasn't able to load the company logo, so i temporary changed the code to upload the image, and when it's uploaded it can be seen by SuiteCRm, but when i try to access it from the folder when it's stored it gives me access denied.
Secondly, when i upload a language pack zip and try to install it, it gives me an error

> "no mode specified"

and the same thing, when a try to access it from the folder when it's stored `"upload/upgrades/langpack"` it gives me `access denied`.

So i think that the install problems comes from `permissions` or `php.ini` or somethings, i couldn't figure it.

i'am working with iis, and the inetpub file, is set, so it can be accessed by admin, isur, the CRM AppPoo,IIs_iusrs... and the read only is disabled.

Comment: Could you show us the code you've done?

Answer (score 0):

Study this [link](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Setting_Default_File_Permissions_and_Ownership_Via_config.php/index.html) :

Sugar directories require `775 permissions` while most files require 664 with the exception of `./bin/sugarcrm` which also requires `775`. Run the following command from the root directory of your Sugar installation to set the necessary file permissions, then Sugar would require the following permissions:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 775 bin/sugarcrm
```

Comment: Your advice concerns linux and other unix-lilke operating systems.
It does not apply to Windows 2012 R2 - the operating system specified in the question.